# Recent apps switcher not working when triggered

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-recents

I have this android flip phone that runs an AOSP android 10 and when trying to close apps using the recent apps button on Vysor, it doesn't work. Is there a adb command to enable the recent apps switcher?

When I use "adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH" it wouldn't work. Also remapping the keys to trigger it won't work.